# consider a set of 3 digit binary number, how many 3 digit binary numbers are there and why its permutation or combination

Tags: statistics

First I am not sure myself if i understand the question. From what i understand there should be 8 3-digit, like so:

```
100
110
111
011
001
000
101
010
```

Permutation: When possible unique combinations matter.

Combination: When possible combinations matter.

According to professor, this should be combination. The answer to this question.

From that i take that she is implying that 100 equals 001. Order doesn't matter which is combination!?right!...you can go even beyond 100 = 010 = 001... all are one combination.

So what is the answer and why, statistics has always been the thing that is simple to say but incredibly hard to translate into real world for me.

I think you would have to be a greater teacher than a mathematician here. Please don't assume anything about me and point out any doubts, mistakes, and lacking understanding. I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually eight three-digit binary numbers, since each position can get two values, hence $2\times 2\times 2=8$. Your list misses $010$. This is an example of the *product rule*: the number of possible pairs $(a,b)$ constrained only under $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ (but no constraint on both elements at once) is $|A| \cdot |B|$.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

With three digits, including leading zeros, there are eight possible values: $0,$ $7,$
and every integer in between.
If you said *the set* of three-digit binary numbers then I do not know
how else to count them.
The number of values is $2^3,$ which is neither a number of permutations nor
a number of combinations in the usual senses of those words.

But you also mention *a set* of three-digit binary numbers.
So could it be perhaps that you are to select a set of a certain size
which is a *subset* of the set of all three-digit binary numbers?

For example, you might be asked to build a set of five three-digit binary numbers.
One such set is $\{000, 010, 100, 101, 110\}.$
The number of *different sets* like this that we can select is the number
of combinations of $5$ objects (members of the set) selected from $8$ objects 
(all the three-digit binary numbers), that is, $\binom{8}{5}.$
Order does not matter because when comparing sets it never matters in what
order the elements were listed when you built the sets.

Could this be what your professor meant?